# how can i process the rows effectively

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 2 tables

Table 1:invoices

[image]

Table 2:invoice_statuses
[image]

I have a rows like the below

[image]

here there are two invoices, with invoice_id = 1, 2

when invoice status is in query, then there is "pending_reason" to be counted.

Here i need the result set as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use count of distinct invoce_id an sum on if for posted  and query

```
select count(distinct invoce_id) no_of_invoices, 
       sum(if(s_status = 'posted', 1,0)) invoice_status_posted,
        sum(if(s_status = 'query', 1,0)) invoice_status_query
from my_table
```

and for you updated .. question  ....

```
  select count(distinct invoce_id) no_of_invoices, 
    sum(if(s_status = 'posted', 1,0)) invoice_status_posted,
    sum(if(s_status = 'query' AND pending_reason is null, 1,0)) invoice_status_query, 
    sum(if() s_status = 'query' and pending_reason ='Pending Internal Clariication', 1,0)) Pending_Internal_Clariication

from my_table
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited a question, actually i use joins table and then i tried to process the result in the php, now i have change the question to process in mysql,

Comment: answer  updated ..  .. but change the question after a valid answer is not fair ..

Comment: apology for changing the question, actually i was trying to process the result in php, then after seeing your answer i got confidence that, i can get in mysql itself thats the reason to change.Thanks

Comment: yes  .. you can do this directly in mysql .. is more easy ..than process  in PHP

Comment: here in the real time tables, i have invoices count to 10,000 and statuses count to 30,000 is there any issue?

Comment: just use proper index  for  join column  .. and eventually  ..use composite indexes  that contain also the others column involved ..  (if you have a reasonable server ..  10.000 x 30.000 with inner join and index  should not be a problem ..  )